# JavaScript to test characters between 8 and 15 characters

Tags: javascript

I have to test for a javascript condition to test for character input on a  form which should accept characters between 8 and 15 i.e no less than 8 and no more than 15. Once i have checked for the condition i to deliver a message to the user. Below is what i am using but it does not seem to generate the popup.

```
            if (PsWd.value.length > 0)
               //has to be more than 0
                if (PsWd.value.length > 15) 
               {
                //test the condition of more than 15 
                msg="The password needs to be less than 15";
               }
                // test for less than 8
               else if(PsWd.value.length < 8)                   
                {
                msg="The password needs to be have at least 8 characters: " 
                + PsWd.value.length +  PsWd.value.length;
                }                 
            }
```

Comment: Can you show us your HTML Markup? And tell us what is not working correctly...

Comment: Where are you 'popping up' the message? The code you've posted just sets the `msg` variable to have a message. What do you do with it after?

Comment: What is PsWd? Please post html or at least how it was derived. Plus, how are you hoping to raise the popup? A simple `alert()` ?

Comment: Do you want to check the length or for specific chacracters? It's actually not clear to me: What does `msg="The password needs to be have at least 8 characters: " + PsWd.value.length +  PsWd.value.length;` mean?

Comment: yes i would like to check the length of the password to ensure that the user cannot enter a password that is less than 8 and more than 15 characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code

```
if (PsWd.value.length > 0)
{
    //has to be more than 0
    if (PsWd.value.length > 15) 
    {
    //test the condition of more than 15 
    msg="The password needs to be less than 15";
    alert(msg);
    }
    // test for less than 8
    else if(PsWd.value.length < 8)                   
    {
    msg="The password needs to be have at least 8 characters: " 
    + PsWd.value.length +  PsWd.value.length;
    alert(msg);
    }                 
}
else
{
    alert('insert password');
}
```

Comment: Ok, if password length is smaller the 0 than it's ok?

Comment: sorry in this case insert password

Comment: is there a way to add a space to my messages ?

Comment: post your message if possible

Comment: "Your password is required to be more than 8 and less than 15 charadcters, you entered a password with the length of: "Password Length" as: "TypedInPassword".

Comment: alert('Your password is required to be more than 8 and less than 15 charadcters, you entered a password with the length of:' + PsWd.value.length + ' as: + ' + PsWd.value);

Comment: For add line-breaks use \n

Answer (score 0):

In case of less code in the question I'll try an approach:

Let's assume we have following HTML form:

```
<form id="myForm" onsubmit="return checkForm();" method="post">
    <input type="password" id="password">Password</input><br />
    <input type="submit">OK</input>
</form>
```

Then your function could be something like this:

```
function checkForm() {
    var PsWd = document.getElementById('password');

    if (PsWd.value.length < 8 || PsWd.value.length > 15) {
        alert('The password length needs to be between 8 and 15 characters.');
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```